# Allow Specific Characters in a textbox C#

Tags: c#, textbox

I need to allow specific characters in my textbox but not range of letters only those ( T, A, G, C ).. the problem is I can't find the regular expression pattern for that.

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make it just with `/[TAGC]/g`.

I strongly recommend you to check out this site, you can test every regular expression you need there:

[RegExr](http://regexr.com/)